# minimize regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

. I need help with regExp for email validation. I have been stuckup in this issue.

Requirements are:
"The Local part and domain part of the email address shall accept the following:

- Uppercase and lowercase Latin letters (a–z, A–Z)
- Digits 0 to 9
- These special characters: # - _ ~ ! $ & '  * +  = and percentile encoding i.e. %20
- Character . (dot, period, full stop)provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear consecutively (e.g. John..Doe@example.com is not allowed)."

And I am validating using jquery validator
and i got reqular expression

```
 /^[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*\.([a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]{2,})$/
```

Can someone minify this regular expression

To validate

**should work:**  him@g#mail.com

**shouldnot work:**  him@g..mail.com

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p6mw3/120/

Comment: You can remove excessive escapes from the character classes, it will get reduced significantly :) Remember about `\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]`, too.

Comment: On a more general point - who determined these requirements?  Are they absolutely fixed?  [This is worth a read](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: i provide fiddle can u jus check with that?

Comment: Does [that suffice](http://jsfiddle.net/1z9y47n0/)?

Comment: Or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1z9y47n0/1/)? You can declare the repeating part as a building block and reuse when constructing the whole RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the repeating part as a building block and reuse when constructing the whole RegExp. Also, I replaced `[a-z0-9_]` with `\w` since you need to also support uppercase Latin letters (`\w` = `[a-z0-9A-Z_]`), and removed excessive escape symbols from the character class.

```js
var rx_block = "[\\w,!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]"; // <-- REPETITIVE BLOCK
var component = {
    input   : $('input[name="email"]'),
    mensage : {
        fields  : $('.msg'),
        success : $('.success'),
        error   : $('.error')
    }
},
regex = RegExp("^" + rx_block + "+(\\." + rx_block + "+)*@" + rx_block +
     "+(\\." + rx_block + "+)*\\.(" + rx_block + "{2,})$");  // <-- BUILD REGEX DYNAMICALLY WITH REGEXP CONSTRUCTOR

component.input.blur(function () {
    component.mensage.fields.hide();
    regex.test(component.input.val()) ? 
            component.mensage.success.show() : component.mensage.error.show();
});
```

```css
.msg {
    display: none;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
.success {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="email" id="email">Hey!</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required" /> 
<span class="msg error">You shall not pass!</span>
<span class="msg success">You can pass!</span>
```